# Get last "ordered" number

Tags: javascript

I've been struggling with the definition of a function. It must take a positive number N as a parameter and return the last ordered number. By "ordered" number I mean that every digit follow each other.

Example1 : Takes 1000 as a parameter and returns 789.

Example2 : Takes 500 as a parameter and returns 456.

Comment: Are you looking for a [definition of what a function is](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions) or what exactly?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: There is no such thing as an "ordred" number, and i cannot see what makes 789 special (except for my glass-ball guess, that you want the largest number, smaller than the input, that has digits in ascending order from most to least significant decimal digit, which is a VERY far fetched guess).

Comment: @ASDFGerte yes that's exactly what i meant

Comment: Edit your question to add that explanation, because return the last ordered number makes no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's working code. Although I don't like just giving you the answer. This is something you have to practice and learn how to do on your own. Take the time to understand what I did. Also, this solution can be improved a lot, just something that I did quickly and works.

The algorithm in action:

```js
function calc() {
  //Get the number in the text input
  var nbr = parseInt(document.getElementById("number").value, 10);

  //Loop starting from the top
  for (var i = nbr; i > 0; i--) {
    if (isOrderedNumber(i)) {
      document.getElementById("result").innerText = i;
      return;
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("result").innerText = "None found";
}

function isOrderedNumber(number) {
  var digits = number.toString().split('');
  //Loops in the digits of the number
  for (var i = 0; i < digits.length - 1; i++) {
    //Check if the current number+1 is not equal to the next number.
    if (parseInt(digits[i]) + 1 !== parseInt(digits[i + 1])) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
}
```

```html
<input id="number" type="text" />
<button onclick="calc()">Find last ordered number</button>
<br/>
<br/>
<span id="result"></span>
```

In you case, instead of using html element you would receive "nbr" by parameter instead and would return the value instead of putting the value in the html element. Ask if you have any questions on how this works.